# Keyboard layout switches only one-way via shortcut in Odin

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, language, keyboard-layout, odin

I just installed Odin. The switch between keyboard layouts is fine if I make the selections by clicking with the cursor, however, using any of the keyboard shortcuts to change the layout, it only switches to English (US) and not to any other keyboard layout. I tried all the shortcut options available, but it was still the same. I currently have it set on to change when pressing Shift+CapsLock.
So when the keyboard layout is set to Arabic, pressing "Shift+CapsLock" switches it to English. But when it is set to English, pressing "Shift+CapsLock" does not switch it to Arabic.
Is this a bug? Or perhaps there's a quick fix to this issue?
Thank you